# Magento1.9 - unknown SQL process

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I have noticed some unknown SQL process on my server, which is running almost constantly and taking significant system resources:
[image]

`attribute_id` is always same - 195. and what is very important that there are no tables like at_seo* in my DB.
pls, help me understand which Magento job can trigger it?

Comment: Can you check attribute using query "SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` where attribute_id = 195". From which you will came to know the attribute name which is getting used in this process.  There won't be any table with name at_seo* because it is just an alias name used in query.

Comment: hi, many thanks for tip, i got this:

195 4 seo_category NULL NULL int NULL seo/system_config_frontend_category select Main Category for SEO NULL seo/system_config_source_category 0 1 NULL 0 NULL  

but still not clear how to get job which triggering this query...

Comment: Actually my question can be like this - how to identify magento internal cron job which trigger this sql process?

Comment: 'seo_category' it's a custom attribute. search the module which is using this module and disable it once.

Comment: i'd like rather to disable job, not module. can you give me tip how to identify job name which calls this query?

Comment: Can you check config.xml of custom module and disable  <crontab>
tag if you find any.

Comment: that's good, but how to identify module which calls this job? :)

Comment: You need to search for that particular attribute in code base, there must be install or upgrade script to alter magento table.